# Use .osm (Open Street Map xml) to draw map in iPhone

Tags: iphone, openstreetmap

I have exported a map to a .osm file (this is an xml). I want to parse and draw a map in iPhone using this .osm file.

I've tried exploring CloudMade and RouteMe but couldn't find any detail or example of consuming .osm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think .osm files are a good choice as a data source for drawing maps on a mobile device. The process to render a map from raw OSM data is quite complicated, I would consider pre-processing it to a simpler format. (Even though [if JavaScript can do it…](http://kothic.org/js/))

I am not aware of any iPhone-ready libraries/solutions, but if you want to explore, see [the Rendering page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) on the OpenStreetMap wiki, which lists many examples of the available rendering software.